# How to detect Entire Face(Not side face,even not any portion of face hide) in android just like CI face Detector in ios

Tags: android, kotlin, face-detection, firebase-mlkit

Currently , i am using ML-kit for face detection, here i am getting all the points when face is detected..but I want when user shows the entire face, then only some action perform.Example,Suppose "click photo" button only shows ,when entire face detect.now its working.. But My problem is that,  if i shows my side face(left side face or right side face ) it shows the "click photo" button , which i don't need..If face's some part covered, or  side face is showing, then i don't want to show button.. How to avoid the obstacles while face detection  in android. Sorry for poor grammar .